# How to find words that are different between two Strings?

Tags: java, android

I hope you are fine.

I am searching for a simple way to compare two Strings and print out the words which are unique between the two, for example I have :

```
String one = edittext1.getText().toString();
String two = editText2.getText().toString();
```

Then the output should be what is the words that exists in edittext1 and not exist in edittext2.

Comment: word by word are the same 
but what if it miss word or some words are different 
example of what i want https://text-compare.com/fr/

Comment: but not whole code you didn't even started ... And you didn't even provide what you need "the words that are differet" ... it means : "this is first text example" and "example test first is this" are the same ... and then you are show some website whitch works different

Comment: this is what i neeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeed 
compare between two small strings  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
i don't need MainActivity.java 

i said i need to compare between two strings what is weird in that.

Comment: you may use `String.compareTo` or `String.equals` to compare strings :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if it's only words you can split the strings to string[] that each cell will contain 1 word only and then compare those words. Goes as follows:

```
String one = "this is first text example";
String two = "this is next text example";
String[] oneVals = one.split("\\ ");
String[] twoVals = two.split("\\ ");
int i = oneVals.length;
if(oneVals.length != twoVals.length)
{
    // determine what to do
}
String wordsNotMatching = "";
for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
{
    if((!oneVals[j].equals(twoVals[j])))
        wordsNotMatching += oneVals[j] + " ";
}
// wordNotMatching will contain all different words.
```